# Rails + jQuery SPA Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

To avoid diving into a front-end framework for the time being, I'm building a single page application using only Rails and jQuery.

Here's the basic structure:

**controller**

```
class MainController < ApplicationController

def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end

def complex_query_1
  @items = # complex query

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render 'refresh.js.erb', :locals => { :items => @items } }
  end
end

def complex_query_2
  @items = # a different complex query

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render 'refresh.js.erb', :locals => { :items => @items } }
  end
end

end
```

**application.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    showActivityIndicator();
    $.get(Routes.complex_query_1_path());
});
```

When a user first visits the app, they are shown `@items` from `complex_query_1`. To avoid a long time for the query to run, I've implemented a more "SPA" style of loading:

1. When the user visits the app, the `index` action is fired and serves the base layout.
2. Then a loading indicator and POST request for `complex_query_1` are fired via js.
3. The action responds to js and refreshes the view via jQuery.

All internal links are AJAX so the base layout is never reloaded, preserving the "SPA" feel.

I've hit a roadblock with routing from outside the app. For example, if I navigate to `/complex_query_2` from outside the app, no html layout is served. I could specify the `format.html` layout, but then the long query has to load before the html is served.

Is there an alternative/better way to structure the app for an SPA feel?

Answer (score 0):

One solution some apps use is using fragments in the url to determine how the application should respond.

So your external link should be

```
/index#complex_query_2
```

The index path would provide the html layout, and you can parse the url in javascript to get the `complex_query_2` part. Then use this to determine what action should be taken.